# Determine if the following integral is convergent or not

Tags: improper-integrals

I want to determine the convergence of the following improper integral
$$
I := \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}dx.
$$
What I did is to rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}dx + \int_{1}^{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}dx + \int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}dx =: I_{1} + I_{2} + I_{3}.
$$
It's easy to see that $I_{3}$ converges, $I_{1} = -\infty$, $I_{2} = +\infty$, therefore I can't deduce anything, since $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ diverge with different signs. Is there another way of doing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Wait, you're already done. If any of the integrals are infinite, it's game over. Why do you say you can't deduce anything?

Comment: $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ should diverge with the same sign if we want to conclude that, isn't it?

Comment: @Smm no it doesn't matter

Comment: Wait, you already solved your problem, and concluded convergence. You are already done.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Why?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Why doesn’t it matter?

Comment: @GAUSS1860 No, in fact the integral doesn’t converge.

Comment: @Smm the burden of explanation is on you. Why did you believe the sign matters?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well, because $\infty -\infty$ is undefined. The answer is that the integral diverges, yes, but proceeding the way I did, we should get an indetermination. If I’m wrong, please show me why.

Comment: @smm that's if it were on the same interval. For an integral to converge each sub interval must converge independently.

Comment: Ah sorry, I got confused, so basically if you have a function $f \colon [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and a $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f$ is not bounded at $[a,c)$ nor $(c,b]$, but $f$ is integrable at every interval $[a, c- \varepsilon)$ and $(c + \varepsilon, b]$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $f$ converges by definition iff it does in both intervals (that is, if the 2 improper integrals exist, when $\varepsilon \to 0^{+}$), and it diverges by definition if it does the contrary, right?

Comment: @Smm (1) Do not delete your question when you've received answers. (2) Do not vandalize your post before or after deletion to remove the question you asked in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2-x}$$

$ f $ is not  locally integrable at $ (0,+\infty)$, so we cannot write $$\int_0^{+\infty} f $$

If you want

$ I_1=\int_0^{\frac 12}f $ converges because $ \lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-1$.

$ I_2=\int_{\frac 12}^1f $ diverges because
$$f(x)\sim \frac{\sin(1)}{x-1}\; \;(x\to 1)
$$

$ I_3=\int_2^{+\infty} f$ is absolutely convergent since, $$|f(x)|\le \frac{1}{x^{\frac 32}}$$

Comment: And what about $\int_{1}^{2}f$?

Comment: @Smm Divergent for the same reason than $ I_2$.